# AWS Managed Blockchain - Can't resolve Fabric Certificate authority endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, blockchain, aws-cli

Can't resolve the Fabric Certificate authority endpoint, per this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/get-started-create-client.html).

[image]

When executing the following cmd:

```
$ curl https://ca.m-UKXHKIC3VRALZLELTJ6DDQRO2D.n-A3TH375LOZFKPIJXZDOYHVAICS.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30002/cainfo -k
```

Getting this error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ca.m-UKXHKIC3VRALZLELTJ6DDQRO2D.n-A3TH375LOZFKPIJXZDOYHVAICS.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Currently having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to SecurityGroups: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=us-east-1#SecurityGroups:
2. Select the Security Group associated with the instance and go to actions->edit inbound rules.
3. Add rule (Custom TCP, Port: 30002)

Fabric Certificate authority endpoint should be resolved then.